# How do I set an expiration date on a file I create in the Azure Data lake using the Python SDK?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, content-expiration

I'm using Python 3.8 and Azure data lake Gen 2.  I want to set an expiration time for a file I save on the data lake.  Following this -- azure.datalake.store.core.AzureDLFileSystem class | Microsoft Docs, I tried the below

```
            file_client = directory_client.create_file(filename)
            file_client.upload_data(
                data,
                overwrite=True
            )
            ts = time.time() + 100
            file_client.set_expiry(path=path, expire_time=ts)
```

but am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'DataLakeFileClient' object has no attribute 'set_expiry'
```

What's the proper way to set an expiration time when creating a file on the data lake?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean `expiration time`? Is that you want to delete file after some time?

Comment: I'm referring to the sentence, "Set or remove the expiration time on the specified file. This operation can only be executed against files." on this page -- https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-python

Comment: Azure data lake storage and  Azure data lake Gen 2 are different services.  they do not have the same feature.  And Azure data lake Gen 2 is built on Azure blob storage.  It has similar features with  Azure blob storage. If you want to manage its lifetime, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: I read the link you sent but I'm still not clear on whether or how to set an expiration on my file (blob?).

Comment: We have no way to do that. We just can use policy to manage its lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error, is that you appear to be attempting to call a method belonging to `azure.datalake.store.core.AzureDLFileSystem` on an object of type `DataLakeFileClient`. This is why you get the error! The method does not exist for objects of type `DataLakeFileClient`.

If you wish to call the method for set_expiry, you must first create the correct kind of object.

For example in Gen1, create the object first as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-python

```
## Declare variables
subscriptionId = 'FILL-IN-HERE'
adlsAccountName = 'FILL-IN-HERE'

## Create a filesystem client object
adlsFileSystemClient = core.AzureDLFileSystem(adlCreds, store_name=adlsAccountName)
```

Using this object, you can call

adlsFileSystemClient exactly like how you have in your code example.

```
set_expiry(path, expiry_option, expire_time=None)
```

Just make sure you're trying to call methods on the correct type of object.

For Gen 2:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
datalake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(self.connection_string)

# Instantiate a FileSystemClient
file_system_client = datalake_service_client.get_file_system_client("mynewfilesystem")
```

For Gen2, you need to set a blob to expire as follows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#expire-data-based-on-age

Expire data based on age

> Some data is expected to expire days or months after creation. You can
> configure a lifecycle management policy to expire data by deletion
> based on data age. The following example shows a policy that deletes
> all block blobs older than 365 days.

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "name": "expirationRule",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 365 }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```